Is there a way to connect/disconnect external OpenId providers IdentityServer 4 "on the fly"
IdentityServer 4 documentation says:
"To add support for OpenID Connect authentication to the MVC application, you first need... ...then add the following to ConfigureServices in Startup:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
        options.ClientId = "mvc";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = "code";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });

"
This example shows, how to connect external providers on server runtime.
Is there a way to connect/disconnect it, when server already runs, like "on the fly"?
Thanks.

What do you want to achieve? TheAddOpenIDConnect handler is mainly used when you challenge(authenticate) the user, and perhaps during signout, but otherwise it is not involved in the users use of your site.

@ToreNestenius, thank you for your answer. My main goal is to give a possibility to change OpenId settings(like Client Id, Client Secret and list of external connections) via Web UI, when server already runs. And I am curios, is there possible, when using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication's AddOpenIdConnect, AddGoogle methods, to do it. May be, there is another solution, that gives such possibility?

One issue with that is, if you after authentication (with any of your providers), want to use the access token to access internal API. Then, how does the API that receives the access token know where to collect the public signing key (for token validation?) usually AddJwtBearer handler only trusts one source.  so, you will have the same issue in all the consumers of the access token.

A better approach is to introduce some middleman, like IdentityServer, so all your internal services have one service to trust, that then allows the users to authenticate using the different authentication provides that you want to support (facebook, google...)

@ToreNestenius, I understand authentication issue, and have possible solutions.
Also, I do understand, that using separate service, could "make it easier", but still... ...this "middleman" service also needs to be restarted. And I am looking for "solutions list reload on runtime" feature, which caused by specific requirements, specifically, restarting services is forbidden...

If you use IdentityServer or OpenIDdict, I think they can be adapted to support dynamic registration. Because these two are libraries, you can tweak them a lot without restart.  See my separate answer below.

@ToreNestenius, as I correctly understood, a solution is to create "separate OpenId service as proxy", set trust on it and restart it, if neccessary. Did I get your information correctly?

Yes, but I am sure you can make a proxy that does not require restarts if you add new authentication sources. using IdentityServer or OpenIDDict. This simplifies so that your clients depending on this proxy does not have to change... and internally, you use one set of tokens... all from the same source... feel free to accept my answer below if you are happy.

Also, see my warning in my answer.

@ToreNestenius, sorry, still don't info, that answers my question... You mentioned, that if I use IdentityServer or OpenIdDict, I can add new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication authentications dynamically(without restart).
-The problem is Dynamic registration in IdentityServer is paid feature, that costs 12000$'s/year license (as Duende site tells). Github version of IdentityServer doesn't support this functionality.
-OpenIdDict, as I viewed their documentation doesn't support it at all.

In fact, that is my main question. Is there an included support or workaround(like Asp.net Core DI reload or something), that provides me with this peculiarity(without 12000$/year, that's not worth it)?

I would create an OpenIdDict issue on GitHub and ask for advice. the alternative is to add a custom logic to make OIDC requests to the external provides and do the authorization code flow on your own, its not that many lines of code to implement, but not recommend due to all the security pitfalls.

see one solution in my updated answer below.

ok, I guess, I found a ways to realize it... Having question, how to realize it in code, but it's another ticket, if havin' any question. @ToreNestenius, thank you for your time and patient.

Hope you solve it :-)

A better approach is to introduce an internal authentication service (like IdentityServer or OpenIDDict) like this:

My rule of thumb is that your internal clients and APIs should only have to trust one issuer of access tokens. This approach also allows you to standardize what the access and ID token look like internally in your architecture, like this:

Warning: I doubt it is a good idea to allow your end-users to be able to add any OpenID provider they like because then a hacker could impersonate any email in your system. As it is all based on trust!
One approach to supporting dynamically multiple OIDC providers is to hook into the various events exposed by AddOpenIDConnect, dynamically route the authentication request to the correct OIDC server, and handle the response.
